# обновление поля mysql если передаваемое значение не пусто

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, есть обычный UPDATE запрос, который обновляет информацию о пользователе

```
    $db->query("UPDATE users SET user = ?s, name = ?s, email = ?s, avatar = ?s,
 password = ?s WHERE id = {$id}", $user, $name, $email, $img, md5($password));
```

но дело в том, что не все поля обязательны для заполнения, поэтому если допустим перменная $img пуста, то у пользователя заменится поле аватарки на null, поэтому я бы хотел узнать, как можно обновлять поле, только если переменная, которая поступает на обновления этого поля, не пустая (null)

Comment: конструируйте запрос в пхп коде на основании значений переменных. Если `$img == null` то не добавляйте ее к телу запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Не проверял работает или нет но функция coalesce возвращает второе значение если первое null.

```
$db->query("UPDATE users SET user = ?s, name = ?s, email = ?s, avatar = COALESCE(?s, avatar) password = ?s WHERE id = {$id}", $user, $name, $email, $img, md5($password));
```

На крайняк можна костильнуть и сделать через php:

```
if(isset($img)){
 $db->query("UPDATE users SET user = ?s, name = ?s, email = ?s, avatar = ?s,
 password = ?s WHERE id = {$id}", $user, $name, $email, $img, md5($password));
}else{
  $db->query("UPDATE users SET user = ?s, name = ?s, email = ?s,
 password = ?s WHERE id = {$id}", $user, $name, $email, md5($password));
 }
```

Comment: "COALESCE" и все аналоговые функции отказывались пахать напрочь. А за костыль спасибо. Через еще где-то часа 3 самобичивания я бы тоже пришел к этому.